# Is there a way to re-read previous Tree of Wisdom tips in-game?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Within the game, is there a way to re-read old tips given by the Tree of Wisdom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the PC version of the game, you can leave the game on the Tree of Wisdom screen for a while without feeding the tree and the tree will repeat previous tips, albeit randomly. I would guess this works for the XBOX version. Previous tips always start off with:

> Here's some wisdom that bears repeating...

If you're not concerned with spoiling tips you haven't unlocked yet, you can look at the [full list of Tree of Wisdom tips](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Tree_of_Wisdom) on the [Plants VS Zombies wikia](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/).

Comment: Thanks!  Waiting on the Tree of Wisdom screen also works in the XBLA version.